# Share WIFI via ethernet in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, ethernet

Basically I have two laptops, one with a working WIFI connection (Laptop 1) and one without (Laptop 2). I want to connect Laptop 2 to Laptop 1 via an ethernet cable so that they can both use Laptop 1's WIFI connection.

Both laptops are running Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

you would have to use the Bridge connection in order to make it work.
I'm not sure about the steps, but:
1. Share wi-fi connection (2nd click on wi-fi adapter/connection, find option "Let other computers connect through this connection" / something like this)
2. For LAN connection set the same addresses for DNS,Gateway...  except for the first one you will put IP 192.168.0.01 second laptop's IP 192.168.0.02
3. Try this, if isn't working try to make a bridge(choose wi-fi connection and lan connection and then , 2nd click (left) and there is Bridge connection).

Hope this will fork, don't know for sure , I used this a long time ago.

Comment: And don't forget to use a crossover network cable.

Comment: I want to be able to use internet on both computers< and here i think a bridge connection is not the best way. I tried to use the microsoft network wizard, and it hang up. so could please someone explain in steps what to do in order to make possible what i want. maybe this can be done through command line?